# LWC : How can I make the menu folding/unfolding function? (double layer)

Tags: javascript

I'm making a menu folding/unfolding function. When there is one submenu, it is completed, but the problem is when there are two submenus. When you unclick a menu with the expand function, all of the expanded submenus are not closed, but only the first submenus are closed.

When I unclick a menu with the expand function, how do I close all of the expanded submenus?

- "The BiG One" is the main menu with an onclick event.
- "First SubMenu" is the first submenu, "Second SubMenu" is the second submenu.

If I click the "The BiG One", the "First SubMenu" should be opened, and if I click the "First SubMenu", the "Second SubMenu" should be opened.

And if I click again "The BiG One", "First SubMenu", "Second SubMenu" should be unfolded together.

Thanks for reading. This is my code:

- HTML

```html
<tr >
    <td style="background-color:white;" onclick={schedulingClick}>
        <div class="interval-same">
            <span>The BiG One</span>
            <span>&#9660;</span>
        </div>
    </td>        
    <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
        <td key={record.id}>
            {record.BM_DPM_EOQ__c}
        </td>
    </template>
</tr>   
    
<tr >
    <td style="background-color:#FFF2CC" if:true={schedulingPeople} onclick={beforeNoonClick}>
        <div class="interval-same">
            <span>ㄴFirst SubMenu</span>
            <span>&#9660;</span>
        </div></td>
    <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
        <td key={record.id} if:true={schedulingPeople} style="background-color:#FFF2CC">
            {record.BM_DPM_EOQ__c}
        </td>
    </template>
</tr>

<tr > 
    <td style="background-color:#FFF2CC" if:true={beforeNoonDetails}>
         ㄴㄴSecond SubMenu</td>
    <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
        <td key={record.id} if:true={beforeNoonDetails} style="background-color:#FFF2CC">
            {record.BM_DPM_EOQ__c}
        </td>
    </template>
</tr>
<tr > 
    <td style="background-color:#FFF2CC" if:true={beforeNoonDetails}>
         ㄴㄴSecond SubMenu</td>
    <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
        <td key={record.id} if:true={beforeNoonDetails} style="background-color:#FFF2CC">
            {record.BM_DPM_EOQ__c}
        </td>
    </template>
</tr>
```

- JS

```javascript
schedulingPeople = false;
beforeNoonDetails = false;

schedulingClick(){
    this.schedulingPeople = !this.schedulingPeople;
}

beforeNoonClick(){
    this.beforeNoonDetails = !this.beforeNoonDetails;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use  getter function to decide  if first and second  sub menu  should  be shown.

first sub menu  will be shown  if big one is clicked .(this can be done without getter also  but kets use  getter for uniformity)

```
 get showFirstSubMenu(){
      return this.schedulingPeople;
    }
```

second  sub menu  will be shown if  both  big one and first sub menu  is opened  hence  you need to check both conditions

```
get showSecondShowMenu(){
      return  this.schedulingPeople && this.beforeNoonDetails;
    }
```

replace your if:true  condition to use these getters.

please look at the working example:
https://webcomponents.dev/edit/KaBurcHsb4T1ru2La4iM/src/app.js?p=stories

Comment: Wow!! It works!!! Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: glad it helped.please mark  this as best answer if it solved your issue

Comment: I appreoved your suggestion! but how can i mark your answer as the best one?? (Sorry, this is the first time i use StackExchange)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  maybe this article can help.   also , feel free to leave it  as it is,  it is  not a compulsion to accept an answer.